# Java Jackson serialization handle on getter throws exception

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I use an **external** library that has a method:

```
public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private final User principal;
    private final Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    //constructor, getters, setters

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not allowed");
    }
}
```

And I have a @RequestMapping that returns an instance of that object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authorities", method = GET)
    public ResponseEntity getAuthorities() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(authenticatedUser.getAuthentication(), HttpStatus.OK); //getAuthentication returns CustomUserDetails instance
    }
```

And I'm getting 
`org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Not allowed`.

How can I handle this? Ingore or set some default value to this property.

**UPD** I cannot add @JsonIngore to that class because it's not my library, I don't have access to its source.

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi And how does this post solve my problem??

Comment: Use Jackson mixins to overcome the 3rd party limitation.

Comment: I've added a duplicate link.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you. I've got it working)

Answer (score 0):

You can write `JsonIgnore` annotation on top of `getPassword()` method.This way you tell Jackon to not attempt serialization of that field

https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html

Comment: Please, read my update. I cannot add @JsonIngore to that class because it's not my library, I don't have access to its source.

Comment: You can make a custom clone class and write it there and serialize that one. Not efficient, but effective